# Regex Question

Tags: c#, regex

In my C# Console App I'm trying to use Regex to search a string to determine if there is a match or not.  Below is my code but it is not quite working right so I will explain further.  sSearchString is set to "_One-Call_Pipeline_Locations" and pDS.Name is a filename it is searching against.  Using the code below it is set to true for Nevada_One-Call_Pipeline_Locations and Nevada_One-Call_Pipeline_LocationsMAXIMUM.  There should be a match for Nevada_One-Call_Pipeline_Locations But Not for Nevada_One-Call_Pipeline_LocationsMAXIMUM.  How can I change my code to do this properly?

Thanks in advance

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(pDS.Name, sSearchString))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `sSearchString` to `".*_One-Call_Pipeline_Locations$"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that a matching name must end with the text you have entered using the dollar token.

```
sSearchString = "_One-Call_Pipeline_Locations$";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you provided no details as to what else should match, we can only assume that if the string ends with `"Nevada_One-Call_Pipeline_Locations"`, then it matches? Is this correct?

If so, you don't need Regex:

```
if (pDS.Name.EndsWith("Nevada_One-Call_Pipeline_Locations"))
{ //...
```

Comment: I only provided those two as examples.  there is a lot of other strings that will be searched against sSearchString